# how do I manipulate natural logs in my integration

Tags: integration, logarithms, absolute-value, substitution

$$\int(x^2-4)^{1/2} \, dx$$ using $$x=2\sec u, \,\,dx=2\sec u\tan u \,du$$

My answer: $$\frac{x(x^2-4)} 2 -2\ln\left|\frac{x+(x^2-4)^{1/2}}2 \right|$$
...which I think is correct?

The book and calc says by the absolute value function applied to argument....gives the answer above **without the 2.0 in the denominator in the 2nd "$|\ln|$" term**...and I cannot see how they eliminated the 2.0 denominator

Comment: I am just saying thank you, to Michael. I gather that because the term (ln 1/2) is a real number greater than 0.0  the answer can be expressed without it... the constant in my answer with the 1/2 is a different constant than the book expression of the answer...appreciate the help

Comment: Two points: First: $\ln (1/2)$ is _not_ greater than $0.$ Since $1/2 < 1,$ you have $\ln (1/2) < \ln 1 =0.$ Second: You can "accept" an answer if it sufficiently answers your question.

Comment: ln(1/2), of course..thanks. You 2nd comment is a bit inegmatic for me....was/is my understanding correct ..." because the term (ln 1/2) is a real number(NOT greater than zero), the answer can be expressed without it... the constant in my answer with the 1/2 is a different constant than the book expression of the answer?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \ln\left| \frac{\text{some function of } x} 2 \right| + \text{constant} \\[10pt]
= {} & \ln\left|\text{the same function of }x\right| + \ln \frac 1 2 + \text{the same constant} \\[10pt]
= {} & \ln\left|\text{the same function of }x\right| + \text{a different constant}
\end{align}

But whether it's "the same constant" or "a different constant", either way the "constant" can be any number at all.